# REST API Filters for 'self'

Tags: rest, api, security, restful-architecture

I have a lot of APIs that are to be dual-use, by both an end-user and administrative staff. I will use preferences and give two examples:

- /user/preferences - This give the end-user their preferences
- /users/{user}/preferences - This gives any person's preferences

Clearly this is leading to duplication. Of-course, I can use only '/users/{user}/preferences' for both end-users and administrators, but then I end up with other problems:

1) The person will need to put in their user ID into each call, which is clunky.

2) Security will now become a problem, as the backend needs to ensure that each request is being managed correctly, i.e. A malicious person cannot put in another person's ID and retrieve their preferences.

What's the best pattern to follow here?

Comment: Your /user/preferences could just look up the users ID and call /users/{user}/preferences under the hood.   Then you just need to secure the second one

Comment: That's a valid option, just wondering if that's the pattern more people follow...?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make the `/user/preferences` take an optional `?userid=` parameter for the admin calls. Then you can use the same endpoint and branch based on `admin == true && args[userid]`.

The comment on proxy api endpoints is good too where a less specific call (`/user/preferences`) calls a more specific endpoint (`/user/{userid}/preferences`).

Either are good options. A lot of people put all the admin calls under `/admin/...` and add a handler to verify the caller is actually an admin before routing to the regular calls (`/admin/users/preferences` -> verify is_admin -> `/users/preferences?userid=bob`).